# DateTime - Timezone Offset and Inclusion of Daylight saving time

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I know that questions about this topic have been asked over and over again, but all the reading just increased my confusion, so I decided to ask here.

I am working on a website where user can store Events, which are connected to a date. This date is stored in a mysql Database as type DATETIME.

So what I "just" would like to do is: Get the date from the Database and format it, but somehow, since the start of the Daylight Saving Time, ech date is shown minus one hour.

code:

```
$date = $item['date'] //<-- the result from the database (2015-11-27 08:15:00)

$dt = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));

echo $dt->format('G:i') // 8:15
```

The Value which was actually written in the "Date Field" of the administration form **is 9:15 and that is what should be displayed**.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think that "Summertime" seams to the common Basis. And the shift to "Wintertime" might be `+1`.

```
echo $dt->getOffset() // 3600s = 1 hour
```

If my assumtion is right, that offset should be zero in "Summertime", right? But that leads to the point I cannot sort out, since I am in the Timezone `Europe/Berlin` what itself is defined to be `UTC +1`

So which Offset does this `getOffset()` represent and how can I display the **"right time"**?

Thanks in Ahead!

Comment: You can check if its Daylight time via date('I', $date); and add or remove an hour. had same problem yesterday ;-)

Comment: How are you storing dates? UTC?

Comment: And Winter time is the correct time. Summer is +1 Hour

Comment: @PeeHaa good Point! I have not coded this part. But the value in the Database is one hour before the date that should be displayed.

Comment: That should be your first thing to find out / fix. Always store in UTC so you have sane data which you can easily transform into whatever you want.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Well, not always. If you're trying to represent "10am in Paris on December 1st 2020" then that would be worth storing like that... so that if the time zone rules change between now and 2020, you *still* end up with 10am. UTC is great for storing timestamps and the like, but isn't the silver bullet many people seem to think it is.

Comment: @PeeHaa The Settings for the representaion of the Time in that System are set to the Timezone `Europe/Berlin +0100` and stored without that offset, so the time is stored without that offset in database.